# How to solve this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, differential

I need to solve this eqn $\partial_x g=1 $.
If instead of partial derivatives I had total derivative, I would do separation of variables and get the answer.

Is doing something like $\int \partial g =\int \partial x$ correct...
Can we do this separation, when the derivatives are partial rather than total.

Is there a thing as partial differential. Can we integrate with respect to a partial differential.....

Comment: When you introduce a function, please mention its domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\partial_r (r e^{a(r) })=1$$
Simply gives after integration:
$$r e^{a(r)}=r+C$$
Now it depends on what the second variable is. Then $C$ is just a function of that second variable.
$$r e^{a(r)}=r+C(\theta)$$
For the other equation:
$$\partial_x g(x,y)=1$$
$$\implies g(x,y)=x+C(y)$$
Where $C(y)$ is any finction of $y$.

---

Consider the equation as an ordinary differential equation:
$$\partial_x g=1$$
$$\dfrac {dg}{dx}=1$$
Integrate:
$$\int dg=\int dx$$
$$g=x+C$$
Now consider the constant as a function of the second variable:
$$g(x,y)=x+C(y)$$

---

$$\partial_r (r e^{a(r) })=1$$
Is like an ordinary DE:
$$\dfrac {d (r e^{a(r) })}{dr}=1$$
$${d (r e^{a(r) })}=dr$$
Integrate:
$$\int {d (r e^{a(r) })}=\int dr$$
$$r e^{a(r) }=r+C$$
Consider the constant $C$ as a function of a second variable $\theta $:
$$r (e^{a(r) }-1)=C(\theta)$$

Comment: Thank you. I have doubt at the second step, where you have written " Simply gives.. ". Could you please show that step explicitly, in that could you please write the integrand and with what you are integrating. I have modified the question a bit to be precise in showing where I am confused. Please have a look. Let me know the precise the integrand and whether you are integrating with respect to partial r..Everything else is clear. I will accept the answer after that.

Comment: In fact consider this like an ordinary differential equation. Integrate. Then consider the constant of integration as a function of the second variable. @Shashaank

Comment: yah but do I write it like $\int \partial g = \int \partial x$  or  $\int dg = \int dx$. And similarly for the other one. Could you please write the integrand and with what you are integrating explicitly... That is the step between $\partial_x g = 1 $ and g = x + c(y)...

Comment: I added some lines Hope its more clear @Shashaank

Comment: Thanks yes it is.. I have accepted the answer. Could you please add a similar thing for original example as well..( the step after $\partial_ r ( r e^(a(r))=1$. It will be very clear then. Thank you

Comment: Done ...@Shashaank Thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: Thanks. By the way in the book the answer for the original (first one) is given as $ e^a= 1- C(\theta)/r$ . You are getting a plus sign. It's all because of the choice of the C(theta). Right....

Comment: Oh yes dont bother for the sign. Since $C$ is an unknown function you can choose the sign you want here. @Shashaank Both answers are correct.